# From Hamiltonian to equation of motion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

It is said that from the Hamiltonian
$$
H=\int\left[\frac{\Phi_t^2}{2}+\frac{\Phi_r^2}{2}+V(\Phi)\right]\, dx~~(1)
$$
follows the equation of motion
$$
\Phi_{tt}-\Phi_{xx}+\frac{dV(\Phi)}{d\Phi}=0.~~(2)
$$

How to get from (1) to (2)?

Answer (score 1):

Formally. For a time-independent Hamiltonian, we have that conservation of energy 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \int\left[ \frac{\Phi_t^2}{2}+\frac{\Phi_x^2}{2}+ V(\Phi)\right]\ dx=0
\end{align} 
which means
\begin{align}
\int \Phi_t\Phi_{tt} + \Phi_x\Phi_{xt} + \nabla V(\Phi)\Phi_t\ dx =0.
\end{align}
Applying integration by parts on the middle term yields
\begin{align}
\int [\Phi_{tt} - \Phi_{xx} + \nabla V(\Phi)]\Phi_t\ dx =0.
\end{align}

In short, we know that the pde
\begin{align}
\Phi_{tt} - \Phi_{xx} + \nabla V(\Phi)=0
\end{align}
will give raise to the above Hamiltonian.

Comment: Three questions: (1) How do we know the Hamiltonian is time-independent? I guess since we are only integrating w.r.t. $x$. (2) Concerning the integration by parts: Why is $\Phi_x\Phi_t=0$? (3) How do we know from $\int (\Phi_{tt}-\Phi_{xx}+\nabla V(\Phi))\Phi_t\, dx=0$ that $\Phi_{tt}-\Phi_{xx}+\nabla V(\Phi)=0$?

Comment: Do you want conservation of energy? If you do then your Hamiltonian will have to be time-independent. For your second question, we are doing the calculus only at the formal level. In particular, we are imposing decaying condition at infinity.

Comment: Sorry, thats not clear to me. Why does the decaying condition imply that $\Phi_x\Phi_t=0$ and $\Phi_{tt}-\Phi_{xx}+\nabla V(\Phi)=0$.

Comment: Basically, you are imposing the condition $\Phi_x\Phi_t$ at infinity approaches 0. Also, to be technically correct, the logic is reversed. You are assuming your pde is of the above form and that it satisfies the Hamiltonian. In general, I don't think you can logically arrive at the equation of motion for the Hamiltonian (for pde! For ode, it's just the Hamiltonian's equation). However, I'm not 100% certain about my claim.